# How do I receive the average of the sum from my dice rolls?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, average

I have an assignment about lists and methods where I need to get the average from my dice rolls, but I get errors and can't figure out how to do it another way. I'm only allowed to use static for this, not private or anything else:
the method

```
    class Program
    {
        // detta är en statisk metod med en int som ett returvärde
        // metoden tar en parameter i form av ett random objekt av
        // randomklassen
        static int RullaTärning(Random slumpObjekt)
        {
            // här ska du skapa kod som slumpar fram ett tal
            // mellan 1 och 6, så att metoden "rullar" en 6 sidig
            // tärning när vi kallar på den

            // metoden ska sedan returnera det rullade värdet
            int Nr = slumpObjekt.Next(1,7);
            return Nr;
        }
```

the problem at case 2:

````
  ```
            switch (val)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Write("\n\tHur många tärningar vill du rulla: ");
                    bool inmatning = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int antal);

                    if (inmatning)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < antal; i++)
                        {
                            // här kallar vi på metoden RullaTärning
                            // och sparar det returnerade värdet i 
                            // listan tärningar
                            tärningar.Add(RullaTärning(slump));
                            
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    int sum = 0;
                    // Skapar en int som ska innehålla medelvärdet av alla tärningsrullningar.
                    if (tärningar.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tDet finns inga sparade tärningsrull! ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tRullade tärningar: ");
                        foreach (int tärning in tärningar)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\t" + tärning);
                        }
                        sum = tärningar / antal; //Doesn't work, CS0019, CS0165
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tMedelvärdet på alla tärningsrull: " + sum); // Här ska medelvärdet skrivas ut (AVERAGE HERE)
                    }

                    break;
````

```
Do I need to add anything in the method or is that just for case 1?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't divide the entire list (`List<int>`) by some value:

```
// Compile Time error
sum = tärningar / antal
```

To find out the average *manually* (in real life we put `var avg = tärningar.Average();`) you should sum the items
and divide the `sum` (not list!) but `Count`:

```
// Tven if items of list are int, 
// the average will be floating point (in general case)
// In order to avoid integer division: 5 / 4 = 1, not 1.25
// let declare sum as a floating point value  
double sum = 0.0;

foreach (var tärning in tärningar)
  sum = sum + tärning;

// try avoiding magic constants, variables etc. 
// Here we must divide by tärningar.Count - numbers of items in the list 
double average = sum / tärningar.Count;
```

Comment: thank you! but it won't allow me to use +=, how do I solve this? It gives me "invalid expression term '+='".

Comment: @THECaptain: that looks strange; but you can change `sum += tärning;` into `sum = sum + tärning;`

Comment: thank you again! Only problem i have now is that Count in " double average = sum2 / tärningar.Count; doesn't exist, and it's an unnecessary assignment of a value to 'average'.  Have I written this right?

Comment: @THECaptain: you have used `Count`, say in `if (tärningar.Count <= 0)` line; please, check the syntax. The assignment is unnecessaty util you use somehow the computed `average`, e.g. print it out - `Console.WriteLine($"The average is {average}");`

Comment: alright, I just tried the program and it works for the most part. However, the average sum seems to be off. I rolled four dies and got a total of ten. it should be 2.5 but the average I got was 1?

Comment: @THECaptain: Time to debug. Put a *breakpoint* and have a look at `tärningar` list: which items are there? If you can't put a *breakpoint* you can print out the items: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", tärningar));`